# Assets not loading in newly deployed Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gulp

Just deployed my rails app for the first time and none of my assets are loading. I don;t use the Asset pipeline but have left it switched on for any gems that may use it. I have a Gulp workflow configured which outputs all assets to the public/assets directory.

My my layout I call:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= gulp_asset_path('stylesheets/application.css') %>">
```

which gives me:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/application.css">
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

My conf file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name dev.myapp.co.uk;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        root /home/deploy/myapp/current/public;

        location /assets {
                gzip_static on;
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root html;
        }
}
```

Comment: In which environment are you running your rails app (`production`, `development`, etc.)?

Comment: @Uzbekjon Yes, in Production

Comment: @uzbekjon Any more thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry, missed the comment notification. If your assets are available in the `public/assets` folder, then the problem should be that your web server is not serving your static file from that directory. Can you access your assets from the browser directly (`http://examole.com/assets/stylesheets/application.css`)? If not, then probably, you need to configure your web server to look for static content in `public/` folder.

Comment: @Uzbekjon ok, I'll do some research into this and try some things out when I get home. I'll update here after. Thanks

Comment: @Uzbekjon I have updated my conf to be as per my edit to my OP but it's still not serving those files. Any more ideas?

Comment: @Uzbekjon Looking further into this, I have just checked the /home/deploy/myapp/current/public/assets directory on the server and there is only a manifest-2b4dbf2188091c99631950a25a79186b.json file inside. How do I get my assets actually in here pulled from my repo as it doesn;t look like they are coming across? All my assets are generated by a Gulp workflow and output into the public/assets directory.

Comment: It will depend on how you deploy your application. Easy way of doing it would be to add gulp generated assets in `public/assets` folder to your git repository. So, when you deploy your application, the assets would be copied over with the rest of your app code in repo.

Comment: @Uzbekjon Thats' the strange thing, the generated assets are being committed and are in the repo but not being pulled over?

Comment: Then, the issue is with your deployer. How do you deploy? If using `capistrano`, then it copies your assets into `shared/` folder. So, investigate your deployment pipeline scripts...